# Buying rear rack during pandemic crisis - go real bottom, up high, or wait?

Tags: rack, shopping

As you may know from my other question, I'm putting together a bike to commute. I'm big, heavy, and roads will be paved only first half of the way.

I will need to buy a rear rack for my bike. Thanks to COVID and huge amounts of people like me, who are fed up with public transport and irresponsible people in it, the middle range of racks is unavailable, and no one knows if it ever will be. Racks are light, but big and relatively delicate so shipping costs makes it unviable to order abroad. So I'm basically left with these options:

1. $15 rack that's cheap, relatively weak (officially 25kg, practically less), with traditional spring luggage clamp. They are made to be universal, for huge wheel range so they have obvious weak point and screws are known to be hard on the side mounted bike bags.
2. $50 - $60 range. Strong (officially 40kg, practically more), but with very narrow top and no way to keep any cargo that is not designed as a bike bag mountable on the rack.
3. I wanted $20 - $30 range rack that has wide top with spring holder and a mount that is easy on your bags, but I'd have to wait and hope they will ever appear, keep the reasonable price, and OEM market will not buy them wholesale. So that's probably not a real option.

I'm not asking which particular kind I should choose. Or rather I do, but my main focus is **how one should decide** which rack to choose when the middle shelf is empty?

---

**Addendum — typical luggage**

- Heavy 17" laptop with charger et all
- Lunch
- Water and vitamin drinks
- Some books or technical documentation on paper
- emergency first aid kit

Things I may need to take less regularly but still often enough:

- SDS Plus hammering drill
- hammock, tarp and sleeping bag
- Shooting range kit for blackpowder revolver, in a metal suitcase

Comment: Buy cheap, pay twice!

Comment: Where do you live? In Germany everything from the cheap XLC RP-R04 up to my personal favourite the Tubus Fly Classic is available.

Comment: @Michael in Poland. Shops that have the middle range "available" also are like "it'll be sent when it'll be sent, no guarantees, sorry". Tubus Fly Classic - shipment date 2020-10-15.

Comment: Can’t you order from Germany? For example here there are still lots of racks available: https://www.bike-components.de/en/accessories/transport-travel/bicycle-racks/?filterAvailability=in%20stock&sort=price_asc For example the Racktime ECO 2.0 Rack looks exactly like what you want.

Comment: @Michael Not sure about Poland, but their shipment costs 10 EUR to Czechia and that is substantial when buying just a rack.

Comment: @Michael 10€ shipping on a 20€ rack makes little sense to me.

Comment: Even the expensive ones will wear out in time, but the lifespan will be a lot longer; I got many thousands of kilometres of touring plus over a decade of daily commuting off my first one.  And I'm not convinced of the advantage of carrying loads on top of the rack; even the bag I had that was *designed* for the top of the rack had a tendency to flop around if it was carrying much weight.

Comment: @Mołot *10€ shipping on a 20€ rack makes little sense to me.*  Do you have any other way to get a good rack that fits your needs at this moment?  If that 20€ rack with 10€ shipping is what fits your needs, and you save money (and sanity and health!) by commuting by bicycle, that extra 10€ is IMO money well-spent.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I might get a more expensive one locally all right. My issue is that I don't know my needs yet and I'm afraid I'll buy something that I can't use properly.

Comment: The generally known term for what I think you mean by 'spring luggage strap' is the dutch word 'snelbinder'.  If you're going to be riding on unpaved surfaces you probably need good quality panniers anyway and won't want to rely on such a thing for much.

Comment: @Andrew - Where I live I have paid more for shipping than the product I was buying, and it still worked out significantly cheaper than buying locally for exactly the same part.  Bicycle Parts is a common thing for this to occur on as the manufacturers award exclusive (monopoly) rights to one distributer and prevent sellers in other countries shipping here (but there are workarounds).

Comment: @Mołot please clarify - what kind of items do you intend on carrying ?

Comment: You do not need to take all of those things at a time? If you go to the same office every day you can save weight by leaving your lock there, get a second charger, use online version of doc/book at the place where you need it infrequently. If you need all of this at once, shop not for a track but a pannier system, rack + bags. Maybe also front low riders. I've seen craftsmen going to customers that way with about 100 kg tools. Expensive pays out soon then.

Comment: @Mołot I would absolutely carry your revolver in a backpack.  That way if it falls you will know immediately.  Having it on a rack would be too risky of loss and expose you to potential legal charges from the police and loss of gun licence.

Comment: @Criggie in my country I need no licence for blackpowder guns. And even if I'll put revolver itself in my backpack or on my belt, real weight is in all the stuff you take to the shooting range. Lead. Tools for field repair. Field cleaning and lubing. Spyglass to watch the target. And so on.

Comment: @Criggie fun fact, I'm even allowed to put 20kg of blackpowder on my rack and it would be legal. Stupid, but legal. No "dangerous load" signs required. Crazy world we live in. I'm definitely not going to do that.

Comment: I understand that getting some downvotes happens, but I'd be happy to know why this post is not useful or good to read.

Comment: When I was a kid, I spend whole weekends being ridden around on the cheapo clamp-type rear rack, and I weighed way more than 26 kg. If I were you I would start with the cheap one and find out what I really needed in practice.

Comment: @Swifty "Buy cheap, pay twice!" sounds like that'd still be cheaper 2x15 vs 50 :p

Comment: @Mark yes but 15+50>50 :p. If a tool fails me I might not rush out to buy the same one

Comment: Consider carrying your water/drinks in a container that fits into the regular bottle cages. That tends to be much more stable than weight in the back and is a solid way to carry 1.5L of fluids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for self answering, but answer was simpler than I thought.

I asked the best local manufacturer, one with medium-range prices and high quality, when their 35 kg racks will be available. They won't be, but they'll figured out they have a few of them in the corner of their warehouse... So I got what I hoped to buy in the first place!

So, it is always worth to try to talk to people, and simply ask.

Answer (score 14):

25kg on a rear rack is already very hard to handle, especially if it’s on the top of the rack. Start leaning the bike unconsciously while standing at a red traffic light and you’ll suddenly do a very embarrassing dance trying to prevent the whole thing (+you) from toppling over. Carrying more than 25kg on a rear rack is really not a good idea. I doubt the bolts and bolt holes of the frame can survive much more. It’s also quite hard on the rear wheel, so make sure you have a sturdy rear wheel if you plan to carry this much load.

I never had a use for the spring clamp on my first rack and removed it after some time for weight savings. It’s really only useful if you quickly want to transport something small and easy to clamp, like a sweater. Even then it’s hard to keep it away from the rear wheel. I’m commuting and traveling by bike and I’m more than happy with my Ortlieb Backroller panniers (Vaude makes very similar ones). They are extremely sturdy, roomy, waterproof and quick to take on and off.

As Qwerky mentions in the comments, bungee cords are much more useful and flexible for securing things to the top of the rack. I’m actually using the detachable shoulder straps of the Ortlieb panniers for the purpose.

One more tip from experience: Tighten the rack bolts to appropriate torque and use threadlocker, they tend to come loose.

Comment: Yeah no kidding. That much weight is about where I'd seriously consider a trailer instead of a rack (just about can't tip a trailer).

Comment: Agree that spring clamps are a waste of time, but a bungee cord is frequently useful. Not sure what the official name is but I call it a "Dutch strap" as it is extremely common in Netherlands. Its three pieces of flat, elasticated cord with a eye hole at each end to mount using the bolts that attach the rack to the frame.

Comment: You can easily and quickly get used to carrying more t than that on a rear rack. Ask anyone with a child seat. They're mounted higher so worse, but 30kg is perfectly doable.

Comment: You cannot transport 25kg on a bike rack that's rated for 25kg. At least not any appreciable amount of distance across not perfectly smooth roads. They are simply not built to survive the shocks that an unsuspended bike needs to endure. I've killed one with a 5kg load within a month or so due to very bad road conditions.

Comment: @ChrisH: I honestly don’t understand how people manage it with kids. I’m certainly no weak person (I can do a 120kg deadlift) and yet I’ve still managed to lose control of my bike (8.5kg) with 15kg of luggage on the rear rack (2kg tent on top, rest in panniers) simply while standing beside it. Once it starts to topple it’s over, unless you are prepared for it. Maybe it’s easier with trekking or city bikes.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: Almost all rear racks seem to have a 25kg limit. Probably a general limit due to the M5 mounting bolts or maybe a legal limit? In any case there are some I’d certainly trust with 25kg and others where the welds probably break apart with only 10kg.

Comment: I'm on my 2nd child seat on a hybrid; my daughter is nearly 7. One thing that helps is having the saddle a little lower than you would on a road bike; combined with a fairly low bottom bracket, and in my case big feet, I can keep the bike essentially vertical with one foot on the ground. For longer stops I stand over the top tube. Starting moving is the hardest part, with 30% more mass to get up to speed and twitchy low-speed handling. Care in when/where you stop deals with that, including taking the lane in stop-start traffic so you don't have someone close alongside.

Comment: There are definitely 40kg racks. I've got a Tubus tree my tourer, and there's a Blackburn that takes an optional child seat. But I've never ever put more than about 25kg of luggage on a rear rack because I've also got a handlebar bag and front rack (I have ridden up 16% hills with 35kg of camping and outdoor gear). Some weight forwards also helps with handling when using the child seat - a D-lock on the fork, and using a handlebar bag

Comment: @Qwerky I've had a pretty good experience with a net made of bungee cords. It came with plastic S-hooks at each corner. One hook has since broken, but I swapped in a carabiner that works great.

Comment: @ChrisH: Interesting, Tubus states that for example their Tubus Cargo is tested for 40kg but they only put 26kg in the specifications because with 27kg or above you’d be allowed to use a child seat and they don’t want you to do that.

Comment: That's possible, and I think that's the one that came with my tourer. They may even label it differently in different places to suit different regulations. On the other hand it would seem reasonable to state 40kg, no people. Rack mount child seats are generally designed for a specific rack anyway, but neither of mine have been rack mount.

Comment: I'm heavy, so I got an extra stron frame that should handle it all right. Plus, with little ingenuity, I might consider using V-brake pivots as additional mounting points. And I'm aiming at 120kg wheels. Last but not least, I feel like it's safer to have a sturdier rack than I need

Comment: @Joshua trailers are eminently tippable.... I've rolled one going around a roundabout, in traffic, which was unpleasent.

Comment: @Michael my Mum used to ride about with *two* kids -- me on the back, and another seat behind the handlebars  for my little brother. We did fall over a couple of times...

Comment: @Mołot: The V-Brake mounting points won’t help, basically all the weight is on the two bottom mounting points.

Answer (score 8):

In your situation, I would buy the cheaper option.

Firstly, you will limit the amount of money you lose if you still want the mid-range rack later on.

Secondly, I don't know how much experience you have with commuting with pannier, but I have lots and the only time I put the rack to it's limit is when I got shopping and beer crates are on discount. I rarely load them with more than spare clothes, lunch and bicycle spares.

Thirdly, you should consider the mounting of the pannier. I bought an expensive rack to raplace my mid-range one only to end up keeping the mid-range one as the pannier system fit on it much better. Consider rack tube sizing vs pannier mounting hardware, and rack vertical tube position vs pannier bottom securing mechanism.

Sometimes, the cheaper racks fail as they come with cheap and weak bolts. YOu could also consider buying the cheap rack, and buying stainless steel bolts (doubt they will come with strong bolts) and test the rack.

Finally, I'm very glad you've decided to commute by bike. And "best setup" is a very personal and subjective thing. So it can be hard to give advice that doesn't include "It's the best coz I like it".

Comment: No experience, loving good beer :)

Comment: I think you might be surpised by how much a cheap rack with stainless steel bolts can hold. Plus, if you don't overload it with beer, you will need two trips to get beer, and in my books, more riding = more fun! I'm pretty sure the mid-range racks will have a 25-30kg max too

Comment: yes, 25 up to 35kg, but it'll be a real, trustworthy number, with no people complaining in reviews m

Comment: For anyone who connecting a stainless steel fastener to another stainless steel fastener, don't forget anti-seize compound.  Stainless steel fasteners gall to each other very easily.

Answer (score 7):

As others say, this is *your* decision. Here's what I decided:

Personally, I use one of the sturdy expensive ones (a Tubus Logo, which has now gone around with me something between 30000 and 60000 km in the last 14 years), but I use panniers (including one with A4-folder shape & size) and therefore wanted to have the 2nd lower sidewise bars for the pannier. I'd have preferred a wider rack as well, but they weren't available back then with the lower pannier bar.

Things I'd look for/consider:

- A spring holder is a secondary requirement in the sense that you can get separate add-on spring holders.
  (I haven't bothered to do so, however: my Sweater or rain jacket and dog leash go into the handle bar pannier)
- My experience with the flimsy varieties of rack is that things get wobbly at far less than 25 kg (easily with a not-so-small laptop plus a book in the pannier), which is particularly bad at high speed.
- I carry my laptop somewhat regularly, and I think a laptop is probably better transported "standing" than flat on the rack. I.e. I use a pannier.
- If you consider pannier use at all: I still find the 2nd, lower bar to attach the pannier a very good idea.
  Since I do use panniers attached on the 2nd bar, I use top of the rack mostly only for longer tours (to put my camping gear across) where it gives a reasonable platform together with the top of the panniers.
- Meanwhile, there are also racks with wide top (12 cm instead of the ≈9 cm I have) and 2nd bar available. (That's in the expensive segment, though.)
- A rack design that puts the rear light into a bit of a "cage" can save a whole lot of back light repairs :-)
- It may be possible to sell one of the expensive racks again if you decide after all to not like commuting.

Comment: Thank you. I know that it is ultimately my decision. That's why I wrote that *process* of making that decision is what I'm interested in the most.

Answer (score 2):

@Mołot please clarify - what kind of items do you intend on carrying ?

I have recently had to start carrying a work-owned laptop back and forth, I'm very glad I have the better rack and pannier.

If you're just carrying a coat and your lunch, perhaps the cheap one is good enough.

Consider also that 25 kg is a lot of weight on a bike, and 40kg is roughly all the weight your front wheel might carry while riding in a steady state.  Most racks would be used for loads on the lower end, (except for baby seats)

---

An SDS hammer drill is 5 kg for a lightweight home user one, and perhaps up to 20 kilos for a hefty solid tradesman grade one.

A Colt Army Model 1860 or Remington Model 1858 is about 1.25 kg but all the other items could bring this closer to 10 kg.  Additionally there may be restrictions on how you transport firearms depending on location/jurisdiction.

Heavy 17" laptop seem to be around 7 lb or 3.1 Kg

Lunch  0.5 kg

Water and vitamin drinks  A litre weighs a kilogram, so 2 bottles would be about 1.5 kg.

Some books or technical documentation on paper - anything up to 2 kg, paper is heavy.

emergency first aid kit - again could be anything up to a kilo.  Mine's only about 80 grams.

---

Upshot of all that is your 25 kilogram-rated rack could be pushing it.  Instead - get a bottle cage for your frame.  Almost all bikes have at least one pair of threads where a bottle cage can be bolted. And water is dense.

Another thought is that a rack is just a flat surface.  Items like your drill will not hold the rack, you'll need some bungee cords or similar to attach them.  Often the spring is in the wrong place or just inconvenient, but the mass of the item encourages it to slide around.  Plastic or metal cases aren't grippy either.  Perhaps you need a basket  with sides on your rack?  Not sure how else you might stack multiple things on the rack.

Also remember your bike spares, tubes and pump and tools for a puncture change.   Additionally, the added weight high up and rearward can affect the handling of your bike, especially if the load moves suddenly.

I'd suggest a rack that has stays going down to the rear hub area for support, and enough of a structure to carry panniers on either side.  This lowers the weight and increases bike stability.   Some systems have stowable/folding panniers but of course strength is lower.

Comment: Question updated. And I'll try to get 120 kg wheels soon anyway.

Comment: The ones I'll have for now should be good, too. Manufacturer doesn't advertise max load but says they are OK for cyclocross, mountain biking and jumping. I guess heavier load on relatively flat road should not hurt.

Comment: @Mołot do consider joining the [chat] too.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the current pandemic it is okay to start building your own stuff.
Get a sewing machine and you can make it just the way you like. You could even start a business with it. Good luck!

Comment: Sewing a pannier rack might be challenging.

Comment: Sewing a frame bag is an admirable idea - not quite what OP asked about, but a great solution.   It needs water-resistant cloth, a zip, and some velcro cableties.  If I can make one, most people can.   And it can be used on a bike regardless of a rack.